# how to increas maximum number of connection in laravel websocket (beyondco)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-websockets

I am using laravel-websockets. My peak number of connection about 1000. How am I increase that?. I used jmeter to check that.
[image]

this is the laravel websockets dashboard result.

Comment: it looks to be a problem with your server bandwidth because if you check there [docs](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/faq/scaling) in there benchmark they break 15000 concurrent request

Comment: What is your server specification? If you tried on locally, I think your computer is need to be upgrade.

Comment: aws t2.xlage package